# knockout - Issue in adding user input to table

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

This is my html code

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: awards">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: email"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: phone"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: address"></td>
        <td ><input type="button"  class="btn btn-success pull-centre"   value="Update!" /></td>
        <td ><input type="button"  class="btn btn-success pull-centre"   value="Delete!" /></td>

    </tr>
</tbody>


<form class="well form-inline" id="myform"  >  
          <div class="form-group">
              <label><b>Form</b></label> 
          </div> 
          <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" data-bind="value:newName" class="span4" placeholder="Name" id="n" >  
              </div>
              <br>
              <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" data-bind="value:phone" class="span4" placeholder="Phone Number" id="p">  
              </div> 
              <br>
              <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="span4" data-bind="value:email"  placeholder="Email" id="e">  
              </div>
              <br>
              <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="span4" placeholder="Address" data-bind="value:adrs"  id="a">  
              </div>

         <br>
            <button type="button" class="btn" data-bind="click: showMe">Find</button>
              </div> 

            </form>
```

this is the javascript + ko bindings

```
function komodel() {
    var self = this;
    self.newName = ko.observable();
    self.phone = ko.observable();
    self.email = ko.observable();
    self.adrs = ko.observable();


    self.awards = ko.observableArray([{
        name: "sohaib",
        phone: "03009496301",
        email: "has@yahoo.com",
        address: "faisal town"
    }, {
        name: "pappu",
        phone: "45609496301",
        email: "asdhas@yahoo.com",
        address: "asdasd jinga lala faisal town"
    }]);



    self.showMe = function() {
        self.awards.push({
            name: self.newName,
            phone: self.phone,
            email: self.email,
            address: self.adrs
        });

    }
}
```

The problem is that although through the new rows are added to the table though form , but when a new row is added, the previous one is over written by it. How do I overcome it ?

Comment: what are your trying to do with your code?

Comment: I added some edit, see if it makes sense now.
Basically its a table whose first two rows are initially loaded through JSON object while other are added at run time through a form.

Comment: does my code working good?

Comment: Your solution is perfect and it solvers the problem I was having. But could you please elaborate on why my previous code wasn't working whereas yours is (the only difference being you used observable's values using () ).

Comment: in your code you are pushing observable objects which are tied to your inputs. When you change the inputs again, these changes are reflected in the previously pushed observable objects. To test that remove the **()**, push one item then *just* edit the inputs and watch the table result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code when you add new item your pushing `observable` objects not it's value. So as you continue adding new items which are tied to that `observable` objects you pushed previously, the old values are overwriten.

So change your `showMe` function to be push the value of your `observable` objects:

```
self.showMe = function() {
    self.awards.push({
        name: self.newName(),
        phone: self.phone(),
        email: self.email(),
        address: self.adrs()
    });

}
```

***[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RNLKF/)***